# Fluent mapping for EF when foreign key not suffixed with ID

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

How to implement fluent mapping for the below scenario, I tried but it ends in vain.

I have two table Product and State, Product have column name State which hold StateCode like "WA", "NJ" etc which of string type. So i need to populate the State column into StateCode and the related State object into State property of the product entity.

Below is the classes i am using. I don't want to change the columns of table

```
  public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public State State { get; set; }

        public string StateCode { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Code{get;set;}

        public string Description{get;set;}
    }
```

I tried the below mapping  for Product

```
    this.Property(t => t.StateCode).HasColumnName("State");
        HasRequired(t => t.State).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.StateCode);
```

Comment: what is the primary key of State? Id / Code ?

Comment: Id is the primary key, Code is unique

Comment: And you want Product::StateCode to be a Foreign Key column that refers to State::Code ??

Comment: Yes i want to populate both statecode and state object

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it's not possible to have a Foreign Key column that refers to non PK in entity framework. Check this [feature suggestion](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support).

If you really want to have that feature, you need to have custom Seed that execute.

```
alter table Products add constraint FK_Products_States foreign key(State) references States(Code)
```

But you will not be able to populate `State` object. Putting `public State State { get; set; }` property will automatically create a Foreign Key column `State_ID` that refers to `States::ID`.

Otherwise you need to change the `StateCode` to be `StateId (integer)` that refers to `State::Id`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of ForeignKey and PrimaryKey of referenced table must be the same. So you need to set State class Id property type to string. In EF you can only use foreig keys pointing to primary keys.